# How to get the radio button Id value using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this code in my view.

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("X", "Y", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "XSS" }))
  { %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select Selection Type</legend>

        <label>Default Selections:</label>
           <input type="radio" id="Default Selections" name="selection" />
           <br />
           <label>Existing Selections:</label>
           <input type="radio" id="Existing Selections" name="selection" />
    </fieldset>

 <input type="submit" value="submit">
<% } %>
```

In my Controller post Action result I am trying to get the value of this selection i am doing

```
collection["selection"]
```

I am not able to get the radio button Id which I checked. I am getting "on" but How do I need to know which radio button was selected in my view?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This function will give you the selected radio button value and it's Id.

```
 $("input:radio[name=selection]").click(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        alert(value);
        var id= $(this).attr('id');
        alert(id);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your radio buttons the 'value' attribute:

```
<input type="radio" id="Default Selections" name="selection" value="default" />    
<input type="radio" id="Existing Selections" name="selection" value="existing" />
```

You can then distinguish between them with:

```
$("[name=selection]").each(function (i) {
    $(this).click(function () {
        var selection = $(this).val();
        if (selection == 'default') {
            // Do something
        }
        else {
            // Do something else
        }             
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can forget about the id an put value attribute in your radiobuttons, code will look like this.

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("X", "Y", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "XSS" }))
{ %>

   <fieldset>
       <legend>Select Selection Type</legend>

       <label>Default Selections:</label>
          <input type="radio" value="Default Selections" name="selection" />
          <br />
          <label>Existing Selections:</label>
          <input type="radio" value="Existing Selections" name="selection" />
   </fieldset>

   <input type="submit" value="submit">
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("input:radio[name=selection]").click(function (){
    var somval = $(this).val();  
    alert(somval);
  });
```